# Can curl store cookies in any other format than files? ie: memcache

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I need to have several servers be able to do curl jobs, but both have acccess to the same cookie file.  I'm under the impression that curl (I'm using PHP) can only store cookies in a file, but that makes me unable to have several servers also have access to the cookie file.  Can you store the curl cookies in something like memcache?

Comment: Of course you can use memcache to store your details. But would you not still run into the same issue with memcache? Do you not have seperate memchache servers running on your different servers?

Comment: What about the [`CURLOPT_COOKIE` option](http://php.net/curl_setopt)?

Comment: php curl only accepts filenames for the cookiefile/cookiejar. nothing says those files can't be sockets/pipes pointing at memcache, but that's nothing to do with php.

Comment: @MarcB: Sockets do not have filenames.

Comment: @duskwuff: unix domain ones do. e.g. the mysql local connection socket file, /var/lib/mysql.sock

Comment: @MarcB: True. But you can't open and write to those like a file anyway - and even if you could, curl doesn't know the memcache protocol.

Comment: @duskwuff - I was just going to ask that, so then there's no way to use memcache for the COOKIE_JAR?  Are we still stuck with local file storage for the cookies?

If there is an option could you provide a simple example with the PHP COOKIE_JAR option?

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, ??????????????)

We are on AWS, we of course have access to all of their database services.

Comment: @comfreak - CURLOPT_COOKIE I can pass over the cookies..  Hmm I guess I could, for every curl request, store the cookies in some database, and then use CURLOPT_COOKIE to use them in the next curl requests manually?